# Is there any real function that does not obey this rule on limit?

Tags: limits

Consider the following rule

> $\lim\limits_{h\to 0} f(x+h)= f(x)$

Do any real function exists that does not satisfy the above rule?

Comment: Yes:  Any non-continuous at $x$ function.

Comment: that's a function that is not continuous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(0)=1$ and $f(x)=0$ for all $x\neq 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Take any function $f$ such that

$$\lim_{h\to0}f(x+h)=L$$ for some $L$. Then define

$$g(t)=\begin{cases}t\ne x\to f(t),\\t=x\to L+1.\end{cases}$$

Then

$$\lim_{h\to0}g(x+h)=L\ne g(x)=L+1.$$

Comment: When you say $t = x \to L+1$ for instance, are you saying that when $t = x$ then the value of $g(t)$ is $L+1$? Just want to make sure cos I don't think I've seen a function defined using this notation.

Comment: @SeraPhim: yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: Cool, thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 1):

here are some basic examples

- $f(x)=x$ for $x\neq 0$ and $f(0)=1$. Here the limit at $0$ exists but is not equal to the value of the function at the point $0$.
- $f(x)=-1$, $x\geq 0$ and $f(x)=1$, $x<0$. Here the limit doesn't exist. Observe though that, $\lim_{h\to 0^+} f(0+h) =-1=f(0)$ .
- $f(x)=-1$, $x> 0$,  $f(x)=1$, $x<0$ and $f(0)=0$. Here the limit doesn't exist and not even the $\lim_{h\to 0^+}$ or $\lim_{h\to 0^-}$  is equal to $f(0)$.